# Refactor the name of a Cucumber step definition in multiple .feature files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, intellij-plugin

Suppose a Cucumber step definition for which I would like to change the name on multiple .feature files.

```
@Then("^the step which I need to rename in multiple .feature files:$")
```

I was wondering if there was some IntelliJ plugin support to allow such refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on the step in .feature file there is an option for that: **Refactor** -> **Rename...**. But it doesn't work as expected =)
Here is an issue for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152772
Best thing you can do so far is to upvote it...